# Skim-coated textured ceiling - do I really need to sand before priming and painting?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, safety, sanding, drywall-mud

My kitchen had textured walls and ceilings. I've skim-coated, sanded, primed, and painted the walls and they look great. For the ceiling, I'd like to avoid the mess (and health risks) of sanding before I prime and paint. Since this is a ceiling, and not a wall I'm going to be seeing all the time, do I really need to sand it? Or will it be good enough if it's skimmed really well? It's already a world of difference just having a non-textured, skimmed ceiling!

Comment: "will it be good enough" is asking for opinions and that's explicitly off-topic. Only _you_ can answer if it's "good enough". BTW- are the health risks of sanding the ceiling somehow worse than those of sanding the walls? Did you use a different material up there?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are willing to accept. Kitchens are often painted with a sheen, which will highlight any imperfections. The visibility of imperfections also depends on the lighting.

Even the most skilled plasterer is bound to have left a bump, wrinkle, holiday, or ripple somewhere. If you can live with being occasionally reminded that you skipped sanding, go ahead and prime and paint.

Comment: Also, note that if you have a ceiling mounted light, it will shine light flat across the ceiling, creating shadows from any bumps, dips or other imperfections, making them _far_ more obvious than those on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a shop vac attachment that will hold the sandpaper/wire mesh and vacuum the dust at the same time. I watched my dad sand our old ceiling by hand and it looked brutal.  Saw someone on a job site using the attachment and it went way faster, and looked a lot better.  My personal opinion is that is is worth the time to sand it.